# How to model a MySQL structure to deal with authentication? With users information separated

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, database-design

I need help to model a table structure for my database.

I have two tables: teacher and student. And to deal with authentication, I have
another table called: user. I want to maintain the information about teacher and
student separated of the information about login (user table).

For example:

```
     teacher
-----------------
|  id |   name  |
-----------------
| 10  |  lorem  |
| 20  |  ipsum  |
| 30  |  dolor  |
-----------------


    student
-----------------
|  id |   name  |
-----------------
|  5  |  amet   |
|  6  |  sitt   |
|  7  |  dolum  |
-----------------
```

Information separated in two tables.
The user table:

```
     user
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|  id |   teacher_id  |  student_id |    login   |   password   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|  1  |     10        |             |  lorem_lo  |   *******    |
|  2  |     20        |             |  ipsum_lo  |   *******    |
|  3  |     30        |             |  dolor_lo  |   *******    |
|  4  |               |     5       |  amet_lo   |   *******    |
|  5  |               |     6       |  sitt_lo   |   *******    |
|  6  |               |     7       |  dolum_lo  |   *******    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

The solution I thought was that. I ask your opinion about.
Is that a good solution?

Thanks in advance.

P.S.: I'm using Mysql (InnoDB)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To eliminate empty fields from user table, you can do this:

```
--------------------------------------------------
|  id  |  user  |  level  |  login  |  password  |
--------------------------------------------------
```

where `user` contains all your students and teachers ID's and `level` that contains `1` for teachers and `2` for students.

In this case, you can use level column to create access in your app.

Another method, is with one table... separate students and teacher trough levels but isn't best practice.

Comment: hehe exactly what i was trying to say :D

Comment: yes :) 4 second between us. I think is the best solution..because you need level(role) for accessing application pages and login module

Comment: you two (@Th0rndike and @Crsr) are very fast. Thank for the answer. The solution is very interesting!

Answer (score 2):

The normalized structure should be a bit different. I would create the login table in a different way:  id, person_id, role, login and password. That way you can have only one id column without separating teacher and students. in the role column you indicate if a person is a student or a teacher, and use only a foreign key of person_id for each line

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this looks satisfactory.

All you will need to do after logon is check whether you have a teacher_id or student_id and handle it appropriately.